# How can I set a string variable and make it always lowercase?

Tags: swift, didset, property-observer

I want to set a string variable and want to keep  it always lowercase.

This is my code :

```
var alwaysLowercaseString : String? {

    didSet{
        alwaysLowercaseString = alwaysLowerCaseString!.lowercaseString
    }
}
```

But when I use it, it goes into a infinite loop. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your code should work fine. You just have some typo. Just use conditional ?  instead of forcing it `var alwaysLowercaseString: String? {
    didSet  {
        alwaysLowercaseString = alwaysLowercaseString?.lowercaseString
    }
}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stand corrected, this is the correct approach. LeoDabus deserves the credit for this answer:

```
var alwaysLowercaseString : String? {
    
    didSet{
   
    alwaysLowercaseString = alwaysLowercaseString?.lowercaseString
      print(alwaysLowercaseString)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! The code you answered before( code in `willSet` )worked too, and your explain makes me understood. But I'm confused that why this code worked too.

Comment: I was under the impression that willSet would do the trick however, @LeoDabus (a high rep user) pointed out that I was incorrect and that all you had wrong was a simple typo. I tested what he said and he was correct.   Looks like we both have some reading to do on property observers. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var alwaysLowercaseString : String? {

    didSet{
        if alwaysLowercaseString != alwaysLowerCaseString!.lowercaseString {
            alwaysLowercaseString = alwaysLowerCaseString!.lowercaseString
        }
    }
}
```

This checks so if the lowercase string is already lowercase it won't change the value of `alwaysLowercaseString` again so you won't call `didSet` infinitely. It will break after `alwaysLowercaseString` is set to lowercase.

Comment: So you understand why your in an infinite loop, `didSet` will always be called when the value of `alwaysLowercaseString` is changed, which you change in the didSet. Doing a check to see if it is already lowercase will prevent it from being reset.

Comment: You're missing the check for `nil` though, it crashes when it's `nil`. Just a minor detail but could prevent another possible question in SO in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since Swift 5.1 there's a possibility to use property wrappers. Roughly speaking, this mechanics allows us to modify the value each time it is set

```
@propertyWrapper struct Lowercased {
    var wrappedValue: String {
        didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.lowercased() } // here the magic happens
    }

    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.lowercased() // we have to do it manually here because in init property observers are not triggered
    }
}

final class Test {
    @Lowercased var cantMakeMeUpperCase = ""
}

let test = Test()
test.cantMakeMeUpperCase = "CAN I?"
print(test.cantMakeMeUpperCase) // prints "can i?"
```